# How to make Sequelize $between query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use node.js and Sequelize ORM for my project. I'm trying to get all rows where stage is "pending" AND date between 2 and 10 (fake dates). This is my query:

```
const stain = await Gyn.findAll({
        where: {
            stage: `pending`,
            lastUpdate: {
                [Op.$between]: [startDate, endDate]
            }
        }
    });
console.log(stainQc)
```

I have only 2 rows in table. I see that one is matching my query, but `console.log(stain)` in my code shows that there is empty array. But it has to be one item. What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
When I remove

```
lastUpdate: {
         [Op.$between]: [startDate, endDate]
}
```

it finds my row as it should by "pending".

Comment: See logs and check what query `sequelize` is generating

Comment: WHERE `gyn`.`stage` = 'pending' AND `gyn`.`lastUpdate` = '[object Object]'; - obviously  '[object Object]' - is not right!

Comment: Seems like `startDate` and `endDate` are not actually `date` type objects. One more thing, why are you using `$` before operator. Shouldn't it be `[Op.between]`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, $ was a mistake! thanks. You can write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is just a typo. Remove `$` before operator:

```
lastUpdate: {
    [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]
}
```

[Sequelize official docs reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators)